# I can't execute command: vmc info

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmc

Here is the error info

```
D:/software/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in ra
ise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate cfoundry-0.4.8, because multi_json-1.3.6 c
onflicts with multi_json (~> 1.4.0) (Gem::LoadError)
from D:/software/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in activate'
```

Comment: I had same problem when install vmc today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall multi_json by using the following command, when asked which version select "all versions"

```
gem uninstall multi_json
```

then, re-install vmc

```
gem install vmc
```

Comment: still got errors: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: vmc requires multi_json (~> 1.3.6); cfoundry requires multi_json (~> 1.4.0)

Comment: I checked 'vmc' on rubygems.org site, seems the latest version is uploaded today, it indeed has different multi_json dependency with cfoundry

Comment: Right, I see the problem now. I can assure you we will have this issue fixed by the end of day. In the meantime you should still be able use and install the legacy version of VMC (0.3.23)